# Upload file to SharePoint via REST API with gulp spsave

Tags: node.js, rest, sharepoint, gulp

I am trying to upload a file (PDF) from a local directory to a document library on SharePoint. I have a gulp build system in place that watches the folder for changes and runs a task that pipes the PDF stream through [gulp-spsave](https://github.com/s-KaiNet/gulp-spsave)

gulp-spsave is nice because it abstracts away what appears to be a pretty complex SharePoint REST interface, where I can supply my credentials, url, and upload folder and it does the rest.

However, I keep getting a 404. I'm new to SharePoint and don't really understand the URL structure, so I'm guessing I'm not supplying the correct info to the plugin.

This is the URL to the document library (which is named DST):

`https://{subdomain}.{customdomain}.com/depts/indirectsales/DST/Forms/AllItems.aspx`

And this is my gulp task:

```js
gulp.task('upload', function() {

    var catalog = paths.output + 'catalog.pdf';

    return gulp.src(catalog)
        .pipe(spsave({
            username: '{user}',
            password: '{pass}',
            siteUrl: 'https://{subdomain}.{customdomain}.com/depts/indirectsales/',
            folder: 'DST'
        }));
});
```

I have tried other combinations of siteUrl and folder to no avail, such as:

```
siteUrl: 'https://{subdomain}.{customdomain}.com',
folder: 'depts/indirectsales/DST'
```

Does anyone know what the correct strings would be for siteUrl and folder given the document library URL?

**EDIT**: It looks like I'm trying to connect to an on-premises Sharepoint 2010 installation, and spsave works only for 2013/2016 and SPO. Does anyone know how to upload a file to a document library in SP 2010 using REST?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the only reason I was having problems with a standard REST request was because I wasn't authenticating to SharePoint with NTLM. I was able to do so with the [http-ntlm](https://github.com/SamDecrock/node-http-ntlm) module in node:

```
httpntlm.post({
    url: 'http://domain.com/site/_vti_bin/copy.asmx',
    headers: {
        'SOAPAction': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CopyIntoItems',
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset="utf-8"'
    },
    username: 'user',
    password: 'pass',
    body: soapEnv,
}, function(err, response) {
    //callback
}
```